# How to submit a demo phone number to App Store review?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I'm submitting an iPhone app to the App Store for review. However, it was rejected for this reason:

> We began the review of your app but are not able to continue because
>   we need a demo account to fully assess your app features.
>
> Specifically, we need a demo phone number to access your app.

The app I submitted has someone type in their phone number, and we connect them via SMS to another user who's also installed and used the app. So, in order to see how the app works, the App Store team needs to verify a phone number.

However, I can't figure out how to give them a phone number they can use as a demo account that also sends and receives texts. Could someone help out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Update 06/2020: The answer below is obsolete. Simply providing a video of your application is no longer enough to satisfy the review requirements. You will need to provide a valid userid/pw and full access to your app. In my case I created a test account in my TEST environment and gave Apple temporary access while the review was going on.

I have a similar although not identical issue with my app. It is very difficult to provide a demo account. An alternative, which is what I do, is to provide a video showing how the application works. In the Notes section you provide a link to the video (I use youtube). I no longer provide a demo account, I just update the video when my app's functionality changes dramatically.

Refer to the the "Incomplete Information" section in (developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections) where this option is described.

Comment: And they approve the app with just a YouTube video showing how it works?

Comment: Yes, they approved it and several updates as well. 
I went through the same thought process you are going through until I read the "Incomplete Information" section in 
(https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/)
Fortunately I had prepared a training video which showed how to use the application functionality.

Answer (score 2):

They should test the app on a real device with a real number attached.

Alternatively, give them a phone number in the demo account and have your backend for example skip the verification process for that number.

Third option would be to hardcode some dummy number in your code and upload new build for review.